# Can I install DDR3L memory into Acer Aspire V3-571G?

Tags: laptop, memory, acer-aspire, ddr3

I am looking forward to improve my Acer Aspire V3-571G a bit. It currently runs *2 x 4Gb 1600 Mhz DDR3* modules, but I wish to install 2x8Gb modules.

I found *two DDR3L low-voltage 1600Mhz* chips, but I am not sure if they are compatible.

Could you tell if I can install DDR3L chips?

P.S. Exact model of my laptop is *Acer Aspire V3-571G-53214G50Maii (nx.rzper.010)*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only if it also supports 1.5 Volts.

Comment: @DanielB I believe it does http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/HX316LS9IBK2_16.pdf (KINGSTON HyperX Impact HX316LS9IBK2/16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Seeing that the [manufacturer's website](http://www.acer.com/ac/en/IL/content/model/NX.M69ET.008) and your computer both say that the maximum amount of memory is 16 GB, it's safe to say that since  ["the [only] difference between [the] two [types of ram] is the [power] consumption"](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-DDR3-and-DDR3L-SD-RAM), you can put the RAM in the machine in place of your old 4GB sticks, and it should work just fine. Be sure to keep the sticks in dual channel, in the matching dimm# slots. Here's a comparison for your reference:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Except voltage isn't consumed but provided.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install DDR3L RAM on an Acer Aspire V3-571G. For instructions, you can check out this [guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/228341/Ram+Upgrade+DDR3+with+DDR3l+in+Acer+Aspire+E5-571G); though it is for a different model, it should still work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

The Acer Aspire V3-371G can not use 2 X 8GB 204 pin sticks of ram  or a total of 16 GB of ram, its only got 2 ram slots and the max ram that it can use is 8GB total or 2 X 4GB 204pin ram sticks! It can use either DDR3 of max 1.5v and it can most defenatley use DDR3L of 1866mhz with its 1.35v max ram.

Warning: Dont buy 16GB kit of ram (2 X 8GB) as you will be wasting your money, btw, I own an Acer Aspire V3-371G and I've tried 16GB (2 X 8GB) sticks and it does not work!

Comment: Not true. I have two 8Gb sticks of ram now totaling in 16Gb overall memory installed on the laptop. Works just fine.